# How to programmatically create an empty .m4a file of a certain length under iOS using CoreAudio on device?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I need to create a dummy .m4a file of a certain length programatically under iOS...

Comment: I presume you mean "filled with silence"?

Comment: yep "filled with silence" is what I need; I would like to know if tehre is a simple way to create it without writing a normal file filling the buffers with silence...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSError *error = nil;
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempfile"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil]
NSFileHandle *writeFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingToURL:URL error:&error];
[writeFile truncateFileAtOffset:4000000000*sizeof(Byte)];
```