# How do i create a file in the default documents directory in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing an app that needs to store some persistence information in file but i'm having trouble debugging the createFileAtPath:contents:attributes: function of NSFileManager, i have reduced the problem to the below piece of code.

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString * fileName = @"newfile.txt";

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];
NSLog(@"full path name: %@", filePath);

// check if file exists
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: filePath] == YES){
    NSLog(@"File exists");

}else {
    NSLog (@"File not found, file will be created");
    if (![filemgr createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil]){
        NSLog(@"Create file returned NO");
    }
}
```

Since the function doesn't take an NSError object i'm having trouble finding out why exactly it is returning false.

From other examples i have seen here [Write a file on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios) and here [How to programmatically create an empty .m4a file of a certain length under iOS using CoreAudio on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011070/how-to-programmatically-create-an-empty-m4a-file-of-a-certain-length-under-ios/10159799#10159799) it should be ok to pass nil to both the contents and attributes parameters. I've tried specifying both parameters and receive the same result.

I'm thinking this may be a permissions issue but i'm unsure if the below code is the correct way to check permissions on a directory.

```
if ([filemgr isWritableFileAtPath:documentsDirectory] == YES){
    NSLog (@"File is readable and writable");
}
```

Comment: do you have this problem on both your testing device and in the simulator, or only in one or the other?

Comment: Only in the simulator at this point, i do not have a testing device. Though i would be curious to know if anyone else receives the same output from the above code.

Comment: I've just run the code, and it works perfectly. First time through: "File not found, file will be created", there's no error.  Second time: "File exists".

Comment: Thanks steve, not sure what is going wrong on my end then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//  Following Code will create Directory in DocumentsDirectory

NSString *docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *dirName = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDir"];

BOOL isDir
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:dirName isDirectory:&isDir])
{
    if([fm createDirectoryAtPath:dirName withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil])
        NSLog(@"Directory Created");
    else
        NSLog(@"Directory Creation Failed");
}
else
    NSLog(@"Directory Already Exist");
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem, i assumed that the path returned by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] would exist, evidently this is not always the case in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

swift5

```
guard let docdir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first else {
            preconditionFailure()
}
let path = (docdir as NSString).appendingPathComponent(yourfilename + "." + yourfilenameExtension)
```